# How to run child pipeline in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have two projects in Gitlab and I want to start the pipeline of three other projects from the one project. It is important to me that the pipelines run in a certain order.
ProjectRoot -> ProjectA -> ProjectB -> ...

[image]

Each project has its own gitlab-ci.yml with corresponding content.

ProjectRoot

```
...
projecta:
  stage: projecta
  trigger:
     include: 'app/projecta'
     ref: 'test
     file: '/.gitlab-ci.yml'
   strategy: depend
   needs:
      - root
    when: on_success
...
```

ProjectA

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cat requirements.txt
  allow_failure: true
```

The pipeline is triggered and I also see the job in Gitlab, but it exits with an error.

```
cat: can't open 'requirements.txt': No such file of directory
```

Why doesn't the root pipeline access the content of the project or how can I build this so that the content is loaded from the project and I can keep a certain order.

The projects should go through one after the other and only if the previous job was successful.

With curl I get the pipeline to run, but there the next job does not wait for the previous one.